# Many-to-many relationship in Entity Framework Core when one entity has composite primary key

Tags: c#, entity-framework, .net-core, entity-framework-core

I have the following classes:

```
public class InvoiceLine
{
    public Guid Id { get; set; }

    public int LineNumber { get; set; }    

    public List<ProductCode> ProductCodes { get; set; }    
}

public class ProductCode
{
    public string Category { get; set; }
    public string Value { get; set; }
}
```

In the case of `ProductCode` the `Category` and the `Value` are together the primary key.

I set this up in the `DbContext`:

```
modelBuilder.Entity<ProductCode>()
            .HasKey(pc => new { pc.Category, pc.Value });
```

One `InvoiceLine` can have many product codes but a product code can be used for various `InvoiceLine`s.

In EF Core I have to create a join entity with the ids and entitites:

```
public class InvoiceLineProductCode
{
    public Guid InvoiceLineId { get; set; }
    public InvoiceLine InvoiceLine { get; set; }
    public ProductCode ProductCode { get; set; }            
}
```

How can I set the `ProductCodeId`?

Comment: What do you mean `How can I set the ProductCodeId?` you have no `ProductCodeId` can you be more specific

Comment: exactly that is my problem. I don't have a ProductCodeId because I have a composite primary key. How can I use a composite primary key in a join entity?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Adding composite FK is similar to adding single column FK.

Start by adding the PK column(s) of the referenced entity:

```
public class InvoiceLineProductCode
{
    public Guid InvoiceLineId { get; set; }
    public InvoiceLine InvoiceLine { get; set; }
    public string ProductCodeCategory { get; set; } // <--
    public string ProductCodeValue { get; set; } // <--
    public ProductCode ProductCode { get; set; }
}
```

Then define the composite join entity PK as usual:

```
modelBuilder.Entity<InvoiceLineProductCode>()
    .HasKey(e => new { e.InvoiceLineId, e.ProductCodeCategory, e.ProductCodeValue });
```

Also don't forget to change the `Invoice` collection navigation property type:

```
public class InvoiceLine
{
    public Guid Id { get; set; }
    public int LineNumber { get; set; }    
    public List<InvoiceLineProductCode> ProductCodes { get; set; } // <--
}
```

and since the names match EF Core conventions, you are done. In cases they don't, the full configuration of the relationship `ProductCode` -> `InvoiceLineProductCode` would be like this:

```
modelBuilder.Entity<InvoiceLineProductCode>()
    .HasOne(e => e.ProductCode)
    .WithMany()
    .HasForeignKey(e => new { e.ProductCodeCategory, e.ProductCodeValue })
    .IsRequired()
    .OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.Cascade);
```